# How to run selenium test using Loadrunner

Tags: performance, selenium, automation, performance-testing, loadrunner

I have a scenario where I need to do performance test on a web application to check when multiple users login to the app and use, then the UIs are getting rendered in time (fast response). I don't want to use record & replay. Is there a way i can run my existing selenium UI tests from Loadrunner with multiple users ?

Thanks in advance
Amit

Comment: Did you try this ? - http://www.joecolantonio.com/2014/05/08/how-to-run-a-selenium-script-in-loadrunner/

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible.

First hurdle is language. Loadrunner supports a few languages. The two I know for which there are also Selenium bindings are Java and C#. If your Selenium scripts are in either one or can be packaged and invoked from JVM or CLR (e.g. Python) it could be possible.

Second hurdle is hardware to support user load. Running the browsers will take a lot of resources. I think you could feasibly run three browsers (Chrome, FF and IE) on a single box. That limits you to three users per agent. If you have hardware to run the number of agents to meet your user load it could be possible. UI rendering times will be meaningless.

The loadrunner script will be a C# or Java project. Add whatever references you need to run your Selenium tests and invoke from there.

However, my gut reaction is this may be rickety. Error handling will add complexity. These alternatives may give a better outcome:

1. Ditch the idea of using Loadrunner and use a service like [Neustar](http://docs.wpm.neustar.biz/testscript-api/biz/neustar/wpm/api/Selenium.html) to run multiple Selenium tests. If user load is low, Selenium Grid may also be an option.
2. Ditch the idea of using Selenium and code in the Loadunner web API.

Answer (score 1):

There is an Eclipse addin for LoadRunner.
You can install this addin, import LoadRunner references and add transaction to your selenium scripts.

Here is a link, that has detailed description about above procedure.

http://www.joecolantonio.com/2014/05/08/how-to-run-a-selenium-script-in-loadrunner/

But yes as earlier said you have to take memory usage into considerations.

Answer (score -1):

No. If you wish to run GUI virtual users in a LoadRunner context then your model is through QuickTest Professional.

The act of rendering (actual drawing of pixels on the screen after an item is downloaded or rasterized) will remain the same for a given speed of video card independent of load on the system as the actual draw to the screen is a local client side activity.

I suspect you mean something different than rendering (drawing on the screen).